# How do I convert this await call to a promise style .then call

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
async function getRedisKeyAsync(key){
    var value = await client.get(key);
    console.log('got value ' + value + ' for key ' + key + ' in redis');
    return value;
}

async function getRedisKeyPromise(key){
    client.get(key).then(
        (value) => {
            console.log('got value ' + value + ' for key ' + key + ' in redis');
            return value;
        }
    );
}
```

In both cases, value for key is fetched from redis correctly. But a caller of these functions get the value back only in the first case.

```
var value1 = await myredis.getRedisKeyAsync(req.params.key); // works

var value2 = await myredis.getRedisKeyPromise(req.params.key); // value2 is undefined
```

How do I rewrite getRedisKeyPromise so that it behaves the same as getRedisKeyAsync ?

Comment: just write `function getRedisKeyPromise(key) { return client.get(key) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding `return` to second function

```js
async function getRedisKeyPromise(key) {
  return client.get(key).then(
    (value) => {
      console.log('got value ' + value + ' for key ' + key + ' in redis');
      return value;
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the _fix_, I just would add that the 2 functions are actually the same function. Don't know why the OP need a `getRedisKeyPromise(key)`, as the first function just return a promise you can handle in both ways: with _async_ or with _.then_. And even the implementation of the 2 functions should be handle in both ways. And last but not least the signature of the second function can remove the async keyword, if there is not need to _await_ inside.

Comment: That was an example to illustrate the question. I don't have two similar functions like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just simplify it:

```
function getRedisKeyPromise(key){
    return client.get(key)
}
```

It does the equivalent task like async or just .then()